# How to get output value from web page max salary and min salary

Tags: php

```
<?php 
include_once('db.php');

$sq1= "SELECT MAX(salary),MIN(salary) FROM employees";

$query = $conn->query($sq1);

while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
                                print_r($row); // here here which code is required to display only value.
}

?>
```

i want to display only value but this method cant be full fill.

Comment: `echo $row['MAX(salary)'];`

Comment: Rather check - http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-alias/

Answer (score 0):

echo $row['MAX(salary)'];
echo $row['MIN(salary)'];

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'as' alias

```
SELECT MAX(salary) as maximum,MIN(salary) as minimum FROM employees


echo $row['minimum'];
```